# Input shape error

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I've this item: 
['6', '1', '6', '843537', '3', '0', '5', '1006709', '3', '1', '4']
with shape: (11,)
but when go to predict with:

```
print(np.array(data).shape)
data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=0)
print('Predict: ' + model.predict(sc.transform(data)))
```

i get this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_2" is incompatible with the
> layer: expected shape=(None, 1, 11), found shape=(None, 11)

how can I do the fix?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add another dimension to your data, you can either use `numpy.expand_dims` again or use numpy indexing to add the two extra dimensions at once:

```
data = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(data, axis=0), axis=0)
# or
data = data[None, None, :]

print(data.shape)
# (1, 1, 11)
```

Comment: it say: Cast string to float is not supported